# Can I put a Grid with elements after a DataGrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a Form after a DataGrid to submit some changes. But I can not put the elements after the DataGrid.
If I put a grid after my Datagrid, components render over my table

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="modifyGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
     ---- Table with Data --------
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid>
    ---- Here I would Like to create the Form -----
    </Grid> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StackPanel](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/stackpanel/):

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Name="modifyGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
     ---- Table with Data --------
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid>
    ---- create the Form -----
    </Grid> 
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `Grid` assumes that you only have one column and one row. You're suggesting that you need two rows, so add a row and place the second `Grid` in the second row. Something like the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="modifyGrid" Grid.Row="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
     ---- Table with Data --------
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
    ---- Here I would Like to create the Form -----
    </Grid> 
</Grid>
```

In this example the Grid in the second row gets all the space it needs by specifying `Auto` as row height and the DataGrid gets all the rest of the space that's available within the main grid by specifying `*` for row height